# On update not working in symfony yml with postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I need to create a field for created date and updated date in postgreSQL.
below is my yml code

```
table: test
id:
    testId:
      type: test_id
      column: test_id

  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      unique: true
    active:
      type: boolean
      column: is_active
      options:
        default: 1
    created:
      type: datetime
      column: created_at
      notnull: true
      columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    modified:
      type: datetime
      column: modified_at
      notnull: true
      columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Below error occurred when updating schema

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException]
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE test ADD modified_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP':
>   SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
>
> LINE 1: ...D modified_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE ...

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is in the definition of your properties, try to create / call the lifeCycleCallback of symfony and create a pre-update function to update your modified property.

I hope it could help you.